# Excel VBA, dump connections configuration

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel document that contains many TABs.
Each TAB has a pivot, leveraging a connection to a database
TAB1->Piviot>Conn1
TAB2->Pivot->Conn2

I would like to dump the configuration via VBA. What I mean here, parse each TAB (it is fine), read the Pivot (fine too), and see the attached "connection"
=> On this one I don't find this property
Or the other way, parse all the connections, and dump all the "TABs" associated.

same as "DATA, Queries & connections.. we see the list of connections.. I double click one, and check the 'used in' area.

Could you advise me ?

Thanks a lot !

I looked with the debugger either the Pivot or connection objects but did not find the property I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable object does not contain information about the data or connection,  you need to look at the associated `PivotCache` object.  Think about a PivotTable object as the object that knows which fields are to display, the slicers etc, while the PivotCache knows the information about the underlying data.

As there is a broad variety of different ways to have a data connection in Excel, you need to figure out which properties are filled. Have a look to the `Connection`-property (that's a string), the `CommandText`-property (also a String) and to the WorkbookConnection or ADOConnection properties.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, pTable As PivotTable, pCache As PivotCache, conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pTable In ws.PivotTables
        Set pCache = pTable.PivotCache
        Debug.Print ws.Name, pTable.Name, pTable.TableRange1.Address, pCache.Connection, pCache.CommandText
        If Not pCache.WorkbookConnection Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "    uses WorkbookConnection: " & pCache.WorkbookConnection.Name
    Next pTable
Next ws
```

Set a breakpoint on the Debug.Print statement and have a look to the content of the variables in the local or watch window of the IDE.

You can also loop over all connections of a workbook and have a look where they are using with the `Ranges`-List of the connection:

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection, r As Range, pTable As PivotTable
For Each conn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    For Each r In conn.Ranges
        Debug.Print conn.Name & " is used in " & r.Parent.Name & " " & r.Address
        If Not r.PivotTable Is Nothing Then
            Set pTable = r.PivotTable
            Debug.Print "   PivotTable = " & pTable.Name
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi really appreciate your help and feedback, and the detailed explainations so I can learn. The last example is exactly the one I needed so it is fantastic.